# Adding dynamic shapes to plotly facet charts - Python

Tags: python, charts, plotly, subplot, facet

I need to make faceted lollipop charts in plotly, which should consist of a scatter plot with line shapes added:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(
        x=df['x_variable'],
        y=df['y_variable'],
        facet_col = df['facet_variable'])

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    fig.add_shape(
        type="line",
        x0=df['x_variable'][i],
        y0=0,
        x1=df['x_variable'][i],
        y1=df['y_variable'][i])
```

The problem is that all the shapes get printed on the first facet. Is there a way to loop through each facet and add the correct shapes? Note that the above loop goes through each observation in the subplot (facet) and draws a line between the 0 on the y-axis and the marker.

I know how to add static shapes (e.g. rectangles) to faceted charts, but struggling with dynamic shapes such as the above. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may try to create the subplots with **make_subplot** instead of **facet_col**.
See the examples in the section "Synchronizing axes in subplots with matches": [Facet and Trellis Plots in Python](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/) and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221266/how-to-loop-to-create-subplots-in-plotly-where-each-subplot-has-a-few-curves-on) .

Comment: Thank you, i will attempt this and see if it works. I was beginning to suspect subplots might be the way to go, but wasn't sure how I dynamically populate the rows and columns arguments ( for making subplots, and then later on in the loop), because sometimes I might have a 3*1, or a 2*2, or a 3*2 etc depending on how big the facet is.

Comment: Although it might not work as those charts are line charts, rather than line shapes which are different. E.g. line shapes have 4 co-ordinates rather than 2. I'll still see if I can add in shapes using this loop method though

Comment: Using subplots worked well, thanks!!